# Unlock LED TV buttons without remote?

Tags: technology, substitute-tool, appliances

As I had lost my TV remote but I am operating it with side panel of LED. unfortunately I had locked keys and unable to unlock it. I can't change the channel or volume. when ever I press the side panel keylock appear. Please help me to unlock my LED **without my remote** untill I purchase as new remote or find the lost one

Comment: Buy a new remote, perhaps?

Comment: I can imagine lots of kids that have lost TV privileges waiting with baited breath for an answer...

Comment: if you can provide the make and model of the TV that would probably help

Comment: I am not talking about parental lock.I am talking about the key lock,my tv stuck at the discovery channel and I am not able to change it.

Comment: Give the make and model number of the television

Comment: Did you unplug the television, leave it unplugged for at least 15 minutes and then plug it back in?  This will hard reset some televisions.  See http://www.fixya.com/support/t26215418-reset_tv_without_remote_control

Answer (score 2):

The best choice I would suggest is to buy a new remote corresponding to the brand of your TV. However if you can't because the tv and/or remote is no longer available, I would suggest you to look for a an **universal remote**.

*What is an universal remote ?
It is a remote control that can be programmed to operate various brands of one or more types of consumer electronics devices. Low-end universal remotes can only control a set number of devices determined by their manufacturer, while mid- and high-end universal remotes allow the user to program in new control codes to the remote. Many remotes sold with various electronics include universal remote capabilities for other types of devices, which allows the remote to control other devices beyond the device it came with.*

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_remote)

Answer (score 2):

You can use your Android mobile as a remote if it has an ir blaster. Even if it's not inbuilt in your phone you can make it using a 3.5mm old headphone jack and an IR LED from any old remote (you may search on YouTube for that) Obviously this thing also available in the market but it would be easier to buy a new remote than searching for this in the market.

Answer (score 0):

Perform a system reset; check the online documentation for your television.

Comment: How to you perform a system reset without the remote?

Comment: I assumed there was a combination of hold 2 or 3 keys down for 10 seconds, like on a phone.  Searching online, I'm no longer certain.  http://www.fixya.com/support/t26215418-reset_tv_without_remote_control suggests unplugging the TV to do a hard reset.  That might unlock the physical buttons.

Answer (score 0):

On some modern smart TVs you can download an app for your phone that will pair with your tv over the wifi network and allow you to control it that way. This is true for my roku tv.